# How to run a single class in a console inside my MS visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following class:-

```
public Class test{
public void testmethod(int i)
        {
            i = 56789121;
            //code ges here
            Console.WriteLine(i);
     }   }
```

but i need to run this class an see the result of the Console.writeline,, but i am not sure how i can do this. i usually build a web application using MS visual studio and run the application by clicking on "start" button,, but i have never try to output the result using Console.writeline.
BR

Answer (score 3):

Build a Console application instead.

File -> Add -> New Project... and select Console Application

Change the .cs file that VS produces to be something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Test
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Test().MyMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no option of building consule application in "visual studio 2012 express for web". this is my problem.

Comment: Ah, apologies. You didn't mention you were using 'express for web' though

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this, as Nigel suggested, is to make a Console App for testing stuff.

However, as you stated, you can't do this from VS Web. I personally have started using LINQPad for one-off testing of my objects:

http://www.linqpad.net/

Once you open it, switch the Language dropdown to "C# Statement(s)" or "C# Program". Hit F4, browse to and add a reference to your DLL and an Import for your namespace. Now you can dim your object and call its methods right from LINQPad. LINQPad will not lock any files, so if you rebuild from VS, you can Alt-Tab back to LINQPad and re-run, and it will use the copy of the library you just build.

I've switched almost exclusively to this, as LINQPad has a really nice interface for exploring objects and exceptions you've .Dump()'ed to the output window.

(No, I'm not affiliated with LINQPad, I'm just a really satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively....

Since the C# compiler is part of the .Net framework, and not Visual Studio, you can compile programs on the command line.

For example take the standard HelloWorld program in C#

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Create this in notepad, and save as HelloWorld.cs,
Open a command prompt and add the .net framework folder to your path (if not already there):

```
C:\> PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

(note your .net version above may vary)

Then compile using the following command:

```
C:\> csc HelloWorld.cs
```

to create HelloWorld.exe.